# How do I get rows for last 24 hours by unixstamp

Tags: php, sql

I have this;

```
$long = "86400";
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE unixdate = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-$long 
          ORDER BY unixdate DESC";
```

But it doesn't work. I would like to show all new users within 24 hours

Comment: 86400 will not be accurate twice a year (moving to and from Daylight Saving Time).  You could use some MySQL date functions to subtract 1 day & let MySQL worry about the seconds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do that query completely in MySQL with

```
SELECT col1, col2, otherCols
    FROM yourTable 
    WHERE timestamp_col > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

The expression `(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)` returns the date 24 hours ago. MySql is smart enough to handle comparisons between [Time related column types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

If `timestamp_col` is not a time related type, but something like a varchar or int column you have to use `FROM_UNIXTIME` on the column or adjust the above query to read

```
SELECT col1, col2, otherCols
    FROM yourTable 
    WHERE timestamp_col > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR )
```

[See DATE_SUB and DATE_ADD in the MySql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Comment: Actually that didn't work for me in MySQL and I had to do 
WHERE from_unixtime(dateTime)  > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)

Answer (score 7):

Use `>` instead of `=`. At the moment, you are querying for entries *created at a certain second* which will hardly ever match.

Answer (score 2):

You must convert the `timestamp` file to date for the comparison.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (from_unixtime(unixdate) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for new users *within* the last 24h, not *exactly* 24h. So you have to use the `>` (greater than) operator instead of `=` (equals).

```
$long = "86400";
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE unixdate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-$long ORDER BY unixdate DESC";
```

By the way, PHP has a function equivalent to MySQL [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function: [`time()`](http://php.net/time);